# Getting Error message "No "concat" targets found" when running grunt-usemin

Tags: node.js, debugging, gruntjs, bower, filepath

My grunt file is shown below:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src: 'src/**/*.js',
                dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['src/**/*.js'],
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                }
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    'src/**/*.html',
                    'src/**/*.css',
                    'src/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    // base: [
                    //     '.tmp',
                    //     ''
                    // ]
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect().use(
                                '/app/styles',
                                connect.static('./app/styles')
                            ),
                            connect.static('src')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        copy: {
            app: {
                cwd: 'src', // set working folder / root to copy
                src: '**/*.html', // copy all files and subfolders
                dest: 'dist/', // destination folder
                expand: true
            },
            assets: {
                cwd: 'src', // set working folder / root to copy
                src: 'assets/*', // copy all files and subfolders
                dest: 'dist/', // destination folder
                expand: true
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: 'dist'
            },
            html: 'src/index.html'
        },

        usemin: {
            html: ['dist/index.html']
        }

    });

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['useminPrepare', 'copy', 'concat', 'uglify', 'usemin']);
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function(target) {
        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

};
```

when i run grunt getting error message as "No "concat" targets found".
I have been trying for 2 hours to solve this problem but no result pls help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Way too late, but just in case it is useful for somebody else: I believe useminprepare will auto-generate a concat configuration and feed it to the grunt task runner, so above responses are not quite accurate I would say.

I would try reviewing the build blocks in src/index.html and check that the paths point properly to the resources that useminPrepare will concatenate. I'm struggling now with a problem like this :S

Reference here: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

Comment: This is the only answer that points in to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process to debug:

- Run the [sample project](https://github.com/Deep-Freeze/grunt-useref-example/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)
- Specify a `temp` storage location (`temp` or `staging`) directory
- Before running `usemin`, make sure the `temp` or `staging` directory is not empty
- If it is empty, run a `grunt copy` task which has the `temp` or `staging` directory set as the `dest` parameter

> The main difference to be kept in mind, regarding directories and tasks, is that for `useminPrepare`, the directories needs to indicate the input, transient and output path needed to output the right configuration for the processors pipeline, whereas in the case of `usemin` it only reflects the output paths, as all the needed assets should have been output to the destination dir (either transformed or just copied).

**References**

- [grunt-usemin github repo: README](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/blob/master/README.md)
- [Concat, Uglify and Usemin Prepare](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/01/20/clean-grunt/#crayon-58b6f83804594529741879)